# How to use Google Analytics code and Adsense code?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

When I setup a Gogole Analytics code it says me put it within head tags. But when I want to link it with my AdSense account it says "Be sure to leave the Google Analytics tracking code at the bottom of your pages."

Also it says "Paste this code [Google Analytics and Adsense integration code] at the top of any webpage in this domain that contains AdSense ads." Where? After  or after  after Analytics code?

Answer (score 3):

This is always better off at the bottom of the page, this way you are sure it does not affect your page loading time.

Comment: But then it does not track load time.

Comment: @ihan the location of the code has nothing to do with whether it tracks load time. The load time tracker is a separate call from the traditional load, and only works in Chrome and IE9, and IE<9 with Google toolbar installed. It doesn't do the measuring itself; instead, it relies on a measurement API that's built in to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

yes at @stefgosselin said putting it in the end does speed up load time !

See [here](http://hacktohell.blogspot.com/2011/06/adding-google-analytics-at-end-of-your.html) for more details !